# Save SharePoint List actions(Choice Field Changes) to another column with Time and Date Stamp

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, choice-field

I am building an Infopath Form, where I have multiple Choice Columns which are saved to a list.I want to save all the actions on these choice columns(Like if an item is edited and choice fields are changed) to be saved on a `"Multi text"` Column with Time and Date stamp.

For example i have Status as Choice Column and `'New'`, `'In Progress'`, `'Completed'` as Choices. So when ever an item is edited and the status is changed, these actions should be stored in another Column with time and date.

Comment: Create a new multi text field in Infopath. And set up rules on your choice fields to append some text to the Multitext field. So if chocie is changed to "Completed" set a rule to add concat("Status changed", ChoiceField," on ",today())

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like charm. But the only problem is i want to save all the changes made to the choice fields (I dont want to replace the changes), If i set rules on multiple choice fields, only the recent one appears as it replaces the old one. Is there a way to show these changes sequentially? Also "Today" just displays the date, Is there a way to show Time & Date. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Now() instead of Today(). Also set your concat formula so that it adds to itself, as In concat(Field, " ", rest of your formula.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SharePoint Designer workflow to do this as it is much simpler to use and has SP2013 support.

Here are the steps if you are interested to try it:

1. Create a list workflow and set the workflow to start every time a list item is  changed
2. In the workflow definition select the action that allows you to modify the current list item
3. Append the "Multi text" Column with the current date and time (Modified date/time)

Comment: May not be applicable to question with SharePoint-Online tag

Comment: I have multiple choice columns, so when ever a choice is changed i have to store it in a Multi Text column. I should be able to save all the choice column changes without replacing the previous changes. If i use Set Field to Value, it is replacing the previous changes. Any suggestions?